# Importing an Asp.NET application to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been working on an image database web application on my desktop computer, and would like to work on it on my laptop when I'm not home.
Therefore I've uploaded the whole project to github so i can syncronize wherever I am.
However when i clone the project to my laptop and open the solution I get this error in program.cs at the `app.UseHttpsRedirection();`:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'

The solutions consists of a database project and a webproject, and i have set the startup project to the webproject, which starts up with IIS Express.

Edit: I have other MVC projects on the laptop which works  perfectly fine.

Comment: Have you set up a secure connection on IIS Express website, so you can use `https`?

Comment: I haven't configured anything related to that. Neither on my desktop pc or laptop.

Comment: Well, all I can say, given the limited info, is that its related to `https`. We really need more info to give you a better answer.

Comment: Try to do some debugging, maybe one of the items was returning null, causing the issue.